# How can I make an existing class member be a protocol implementation?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, swift-protocols

My issue is simple. I have a class that manages all my viewcontroller to viewcontroller transition animations, and it takes classes from a protocol, because I want to make it portable and I usually make a baseviewcontroller with project-specific stuff.

The protocol is something like this:

```
protocol AnimatedViewController {
    var view: UIView { get set }
    func animateViews()
}
```

But when I let a `UIViewController` inherit from this, I get errors that `view` is not defined. When I define it, it tells me that it's already defined.

How can I have `view` defined in my protocol and have it be the `view` already defined in `UIViewController`?

<sup>PS: Don't really know how to name the title, so edits are welcome.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use where clause in your protocol and you don't need `view` property.

```
protocol AnimatedViewController where Self:UIViewController {
    func animateViews()
}

class TVC : UIViewController, AnimatedViewController {
    func animateViews() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`view` in `UIViewController` is a force unwrapped `UIView`, so just define your protocol as this:

```
protocol AnimatedViewController {
    var view: UIView! { get set }
    func animateViews()
}
```

And `view` from `UIViewController` will be used to satisfy the requirement of this protocol.

E.g.:

```
class MyController: UIViewController, AnimatedViewController {

    func animateViews() {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```